# 'Alt'+'Shift' Gnome problem on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, cursor

I have seen many answers on the problem where <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> cause the usual firefox problem, but that's not my case. **When I press this key combination my cursor goes to the beginning of the text**. It's ultra annoying. I think this behavior is closely related to the messenger (facebook) app, but I am not sure.

Of course I use this combination as a keyboard layout switch.